# GeoJSON Feature not showing on map

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet, geojson

I am trying to format JSON to GeoJSON and display on a Leaflet map with a custom icon I've created. This works using L.Marker (which is commented out) however nothing appears when trying to add the geojson feature to the map.

```
busses.forEach(function(bus) {
    /*L.marker([bus.vehicle.position.latitude, bus.vehicle.position.longitude], {rotationAngle: bus.vehicle.position.bearing, icon: busIcon}).addTo(layerGroup)
    .bindPopup(FormatBusInformation(bus));*/

    var geojsonFeature = {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "id": bus.id,
            "route": bus.vehicle.trip.routeId,
            "popupContent": "Coming Soon"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [bus.vehicle.position.latitude, bus.vehicle.position.longitude]
        }
    };

    L.geoJSON(geojsonFeature, {
        pointToLayer: (feature, latlng) => {
          return L.marker(latlng, { icon: busIcon });
        }
      }).addTo(map);

  });
```

Comment: GeoJSON coordinates uses longitude,latitude rather than latitude,longitude. See e.g. https://macwright.org/lonlat/

Comment: @IvanSanchez That was my issue. Thank you for pointing it out.